Relation between $h^0(X)$ and $h^0(X^{red})$ for a projective scheme X
Let us take a projective scheme $X$ (e.g. a non reduced curve) and denote by $X^{red}$ the scheme defined by replacing all the affine open scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ of $X$ by $\operatorname{Spec}(A^{red})$ where $A^{red}$ is the quotient of $A$ by its nilradical.
Is there a relation between the cohomology (or even the Hilbert polynomial) of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_{X^{red}}$ ?
I think one could show that $$ h^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \geq h^0(X^{red},\mathcal{O}_{X^{red}})$$ but I have no idea how to do this.
Thanks for reading !
